# map action with select tag in struts 2

Tags: struts2

```
  <s:select name="country" list="countryList" listKey="countryId" 
     listValue="countryName" headerKey="0" headerValue="Country"
     label="Select a country" />
```

country.java

```
    package vaannila;

    public class Country {

      private int countryId;

      private String countryName;

      Country(int countryId, String countryName) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
        this.countryName = countryName;
      }

      public int getCountryId() {
        return countryId;
      }

      public void setCountryId(int countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
      }

      public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
      }

      public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
      }
}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWorld {

private String message;

private String userName;
private String gender;
private boolean language;
private ArrayList<Country> countryList;

public HelloWorld(){
countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
    countryList.add(new Country(1, "India"));
    countryList.add(new Country(2, "USA"));
    countryList.add(new Country(3, "France"));

}   

public boolean isLanguage() {
    return language;
}

public void setLanguage(boolean language) {
    this.language = language;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public ArrayList<Country> getCountryList() {
    return countryList;
}

public void setCountryList(ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
    this.countryList = countryList;
}

public String execute()  {
    setMessage("Hello " + getUserName());
    return "SUCCESS";
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
}
```

struts.xml

```
<struts>
  <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
  <package name="default"  extends="struts-default">
     <action name="HelloWorld" class="vaannila.HelloWorld">
        <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
     </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

Http status 500

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'country': The requested list key 'countryList' could not be resolved as a collection/array

this is the error comming.
can anyone help me

Comment: My understanding is that you are choosing the country from the list and while submittimg you are getting this exception(correct me if this is not the case). You have not mentioned the action mapping for the page where you are populating the list to submit.

Comment: You didnt clear me.Which of the action is not working, the one which populates the list or the other which submits it?Also i need to see the other action mapping

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `country` instance variable and appropriate getter/setters in your `HelloWorld` action class...